# Opposite of unconditional love

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a good expression of a situation, when person A likes person B, but

- only under certain conditions (such as B isn't too hard to get, B reciprocates) and
- doesn't derive any strong, positive emotions from the mere fact that B exists.

Is there a better expression than **consumerist love**?

Example sentence: *One of the topics of novel X is unconditional love and how it's better than [...].*

Comment: ...conditional love? :P

Comment: It's clear his question/post isn't looking for ifs, but but(t)s :P

Comment: That doesn't sound like any kind of love at all. They like them but they don't derive any strong positive emotions from the fact that person B exists?  It doesn't even sound like they like person B very much.

Comment: See my answer @MaxWilliams, i think we're now covering what the OP wants.

Comment: *A love of convenience*... *needs-based love*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cupboard Love  is a phrase meaning love primarily motivated by the benefits the relationship brings, rather than emotional attachment or commitment.

Comment: I don't know, is a really good answer, but is it actually love? Or just "love"?

Answer (score 1):

What about ***[uncommitted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uncommitted) love***:

> - not pledged or bound, as to a specific course of action or cause.

Usage examples:

> - in the transition from the innocence of the 1950s through America's struggles in the War years of the 60s and 70s, the pervasiveness and perversity of an unrelenting technocracy, uncommitted love, divorce, family disintegration, and hope.[Cosmic Surgery and Fractured Visions](https://books.google.it/books?id=Qv-N-Ks1GXMC&pg=PA171&dq=%22uncommitted%20love%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw7pC5nrHLAhXBcA8KHV62C5IQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22uncommitted%20love%22&f=false)
> - Was he the reincarnation of the man who had seduced Serenity's mother and led her to her death? If not that, what did the young man represent? Youth, freedom, innocent flirtation? Or uncommitted love? [Abyssinian Chronicles](https://books.google.it/books?id=IdOzAAAAIAAJ&q=%22uncommitted%20love%22&dq=%22uncommitted%20love%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw7pC5nrHLAhXBcA8KHV62C5IQ6AEIRzAF)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, let's examine this a bit.

*Conditional*, or *consumerist love* isn't the antonym you are looking for, as unconditional love is the pure distilled affection. I think you're looking for a complete antonym, that's both the negative of unconditional, and love.

- Conditionals to action
- Conditionals towards recipient
- Conditions, or the lack of, about recipient

I'd say that whoever is A going for whoever B, wants to **score**.
Scoring is a douchebag/urban terminology for easy one time stands/sex.
No feelings or attachments, recipient has to be completely open and willing(don't venture into feminazi guarded consent territory)... fits the bill perfectly.

*"Unconditional love better than scoring"*

If we are talking about non-sexual activities, or something void of body parts touching, A is **using** B.

Answer (score 0):

You might describe such a person colloquially as [*'choosy'*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/choosy)

> **Choosy** - adjective, choosier, choosiest.
>
> 1 - hard to please, particular; fastidious, especially in making a selection:
>
> *She's too choosy about food.*
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Whilst not exclusively used in matters of love, it is a common usage, in the right context, to describe someone who is selective about who/how they love.

See also [*'picky'*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/picky?s=t) (www.dictionary.com)